# communicating between flex php

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

This is my first flex application i have written a php class for the purpose of getting the results from the database. the service definitely works but i'm having difficulty getting flash to list the results and don't understand how i can call the function from within flash properly.

heres the php:

```
<?php
 class CityService {

  public function getCitys($q) {

  $con = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password','database') or die(mysqli_connect_error());

  $sql="SELECT * FROM city WHERE countrycode ='".$q."'";

  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('query Failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));

  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

      $rows[] = $row;

  }
  return $rows;
  }

}
?>
```

then i try to pick up the function in flash and display results according to the value given for $q but flash doesn't display the results, when i set the service up it all shows it to be working and can get results back in builder but when i try set everything up `mxml` and then run it i get nothing back

this is a sample of the flash mxml with all the relevant parts:

```
   <fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                    protected function button_clickHandler_100():void
    {
        currentState='data';
    }

        protected function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        getCitysResult.token = cityservice.getCitys('GB');
    }
        ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:states>
      <s:State fc:color="0x0003a3" name="europe"/>
      <s:State name="data" fc:color="0x0081cc"/>
    </s:states>


      <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getCitysResult"/>
        <cityservice:Cityservice id="cityservice" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
      </fx:Declarations>


      <s:Button click="button_clickHandler_100()" id="button128" includeIn="europe" skinClass="components.englandButton" x="101" y="135"/>


      <mx:DataGrid includeIn="data" x="23" y="37" id="dataGrid" creationComplete="dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" dataProvider="{getCitysResult.lastResult}">
        <mx:columns>
          <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="citycode" dataField="citycode"/>
          <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="id" dataField="id"/>
          <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="countrycode" dataField="countrycode"/>
          <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="city" dataField="city"/>
        </mx:columns>
      </mx:DataGrid>
```

am i missing something here? apart from the rest of the design layer, am i giving the value to cities php service properly? how could i bind GB to the button and supply that back to the cities function that way? also the main problem i'm getting no results when i go to the page???

this is the actionscript:

```
package services.cityservice
{

public class Cityservice extends _Super_Cityservice
{


 }

 }
```

and also the getCitys function

```
package services.cityservice
 {
 import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
 import com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.RemoteObjectServiceWrapper;
 import com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility;
 import mx.rpc.AbstractOperation;
 import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
 import mx.rpc.remoting.Operation;
 import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;
 import valueObjects.Citydata;

 import mx.collections.ItemResponder;
 import com.adobe.fiber.valueobjects.AvailablePropertyIterator;

 [ExcludeClass]
 internal class _Super_Cityservice extends com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.RemoteObjectServiceWrapper
 {      

// Constructor
public function _Super_Cityservice()
{
    // initialize service control
    _serviceControl = new mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject();

    var operations:Object = new Object();
    var operation:mx.rpc.remoting.Operation;

    operation = new mx.rpc.remoting.Operation(null, "getCitys");
     operation.resultElementType = valueObjects.Citydata;
    operations["getCitys"] = operation;

    valueObjects.Citydata._initRemoteClassAlias();

    _serviceControl.operations = operations;   
    _serviceControl.convertResultHandler = com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility.convertResultHandler;
    _serviceControl.source = "cityservice";
    _serviceControl.endpoint = "gateway.php";
    destination = "cityservice";



     model_internal::initialize();
}


   public function getCitys(q:Object) : mx.rpc.AsyncToken
{
    var _internal_operation:mx.rpc.AbstractOperation = _serviceControl.getOperation("getCitys");
    var _internal_token:mx.rpc.AsyncToken = _internal_operation.send(q) ;

    return _internal_token;
}
```

Comment: You are including a CityService class in your Flex application. Please show the code for that class.

Comment: the cityservice class is in the first code section the php

Comment: No that is a class written in PHP, which will usually run on a remote server. You are trying to write an ActionScript project which will run client side, so it would be nice to see what the ActionScript counterpart of your service looks like. I am guessing you are importing and generating actionscript from within Flash Builder?

Comment: yes i am using flash builder to automatically generate the actionscript its all generated from the php service above